# Responsive Props in Vue Component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a prop called `src` in a Vue Component that binds to a `:style` like this:

```
<template>
  <section :class="color" class="hero" :style="{ backgroundImage: src && 'url(' + src + ')' }">
    <slot></slot>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['src', 'color']
  }
</script>
```

What I would like to do is to create a list of responsive props that get used depending on the device or screen size of the site visitor.

For instance, I imagine a list of props like `src-sm`, `src-md`, `src-lg`, etc.  The user would enter different image urls for different device sizes and the style attr would use the appropriate url depending on the screen/size.

Is this possible in VueJS. If so, any idea how?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/ ?

Comment: You haven't showed anything about image sizes and how you will determine if you need `src-md` or `src-lg`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RoyJ That looks great, but I don't think it works for background images (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @AndreyPopov Images sizes can be overridden by the user, but the defaults will be based on the default sizes in vueitfyjs. I haven't tried much yet (right now I'm looking into using an event listener after the component has been mounted -- but I have run into errors in trying to get things set up.

Comment: Background images are CSS, which uses media queries for responsive design. See https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/

Comment: Take a look at [vue-match-media](https://github.com/drenglish/vue-match-media).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuently what you are trying to do is not trivial. This is because inline style tags can not accept media queries.

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax) declares:

> The value of the style attribute must match the syntax of the contents of a CSS declaration block

---

**Solution 1:** 
This solution is the simplest, perhaps not entirely what you are looking for.

It works by including `img` elements, and showing an hiding them via CSS.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img class="image--sm" :src="src.sm" />
        <img class="image--md" :src="src.md" />
        <img class="image--lg" :src="src.lg" />
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            src: Object
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .image--md,
    .image--lg {
        display: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: 400px) {
        .image--sm {
            display: none;
        }

        .image--md {
          display: block;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
        .image--md {
            display: none;
        }

        .image--lg {
            display: block;
        }
    }
</style>
```

> Example: https://jsfiddle.net/h3c5og08/1/

---

**Solution 2:**

Image tags may not be the desired effect you are trying to achieve. This solution creates a style tag in the head and injecting the css content to change the background images.

You can not have style tags in Vue template. It will throw an error like:

> Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.

As the error describes vue is designed the map state the UI. Using `style` tags in the template is prohibited because you can cause leaks to the outer world.

Although you can not declaratively styles in a template, we can use a bit of JS in the mounted hook of the component to add targetted and dynamic styles.

First we will need to constrain dynamic styles to this element. We can use the internal id of the created component `this._uid`, attaching to scope the css. (Note this is internal API so can be subject to change)

```
<template>
    <div class="image" :data-style-scope="_uid">
    </div>
</template>
```

The next part is to generate the style in a computed property, to later inject into a style block. You can expand on this computed property, to conditionaly assign properties ect. Note: keep the properties to the dynamic values only.

```
css () {
    const selector = `.image[data-style-scope="${this._uid}"]`
    const img = val => `${selector} { background-image: url("${val}"); }`
    const sm = img(this.sm)
    const md = img(this.md)
    const lg = img(this.lg)

    return `
        ${sm}
        @media (min-width: 200px) { ${md} }
        @media (min-width: 300px) { ${lg} }
    `    
}
```

This generated string from the `css` computed property is what we will now use when creating the style tag at mount. At mount we create a style node and append to the head. Assigning the nodes to the vm for references.

Using the references in the vm we can watch changes to the computed updating the style node.

Remember to clean up before destorying the component, removing the style node.

```
{
    data () {
        return {
            // Reference data properties
            style: null,
            styleRef: null
        }
    },

    mounted () {
        // Create style node
        let style = document.createElement('style')
        style.type = "text/css"
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''))

        // Assign references on vm
        this.styleRef = style
        this.style = style.childNodes[0]

        // Assign css the the style node
        this.style.textContent = this.css

        // Append to the head
        document.head.appendChild(style)
    },

    beforeDestroy () {
        // Remove the style node from the head
        this.style.parentElement.removeChild(this.style)
    },

    computed: {
        css () {
            // ...
        }
    },

    watch: {
        css (value) {
            // On css value change update style content
            this.style.textContent = this.css
        }
    }
}
```

> Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bLkc51Lz/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the module described here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-responsive-components/ which is called vue-responsive-components

It lets the component change its CSS depending on its own width (not on the entire browser's width)